# jQuery Ajax Problem

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to figure out what I am doing wrong here. Basically I'm trying to get a successful callback from:

```
http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer/project?f=pjson&inSR=4326&outSR=102113&geometries={"geometryType":"esriGeometryPoint","geometries":[{"x":-117,"y":34}]}
```

When pasting this into a browser, I get data, when I'm doing this in Javascript it doesn't work as it calls the error handler. Any ideas? I've used fiddler to compare the requests and found really no difference.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer/project?f=pjson&inSR=4326&outSR=102113&geometries={"geometryType":"esriGeometryPoint","geometries":[{"x":-117,"y":34}]}',
    success:    function(data){ 
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('error');
    }   
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work as in nothing happens, doesn't work as in your error function gets called, doesn't work as in your success function is called but without the data or doesn't work as in whenever you try it your computer catches fire? Or some other "doesn't work".

Comment: Doesn't work as in the error handler is called.

Comment: @LB - what is the textStatus and response code of the error?

Comment: @LB - what is the errorThrown?

Answer (score 4):

Add a jsonp paremeter:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    url: 'http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer/project?f=pjson&inSR=4326&outSR=102113&geometries={"geometryType":"esriGeometryPoint","geometries":[{"x":-117,"y":34}]}',
    success:    function(data){ 
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('error');
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a jsonp request. In jQuery 1.5 you can set [crossDomain](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to true.

Answer (score 2):

Unless your website is at sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com, you are running into cross-site scripting concerns.

To mitigate them you can:

1. Run your request through a proxy on your own server to your site.
2. Use [JSPONP](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/), if the domain you are requesting information from supports it.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ and set your jsonp callback

```
$.getJSON('http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer/project?f=pjson&callback=?&inSR=4326&outSR=102113&geometries={"geometryType":"esriGeometryPoint","geometries":[{"x":-117,"y":34}]}', function(res)
{

});
```

something like that might work, notice the &callback=? in the query string that was added.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have had the same problem. From my perspective, it seems ESRI has a funny way of understanding status codes.

The issue is that you received a 200 back from the server, which is supposed to signify a success. However, the transmission you are receiving from ESRI is an error. What I have to do with my ESRI ajax calls is to parse the response...

```
parse: function(response) {
    if (response.error) { //If there is a server error, it will find it here.
        this.searchError(response.error); //I would then send to the error function.
    }
    return response.features
}
```